# find local minimum in a time series data (csv file)

Tags: python-3.x

I am a new user of Python 3.
I have a time series data (daily data) stored in a csv file. 
The data looks like:

```
date       value
06/09/2016  1
06/10/2016  1.1
06/11/2016  1.1
06/12/2016  1
06/13/2016  1.2
06/14/2016  1.5
06/15/2016  1.5
06/16/2016  1.3
06/17/2016  1.3
06/18/2016  1.3
06/19/2016  1.2
06/20/2016  1.3
06/21/2016  1.2
06/22/2016  1.2
06/23/2016  1.5
06/24/2016  1.6
06/25/2016  1.8
06/26/2016  1.7
06/27/2016  1.5
06/28/2016  1.9
06/29/2016  2
06/30/2016  1.9
07/01/2016  1.8
07/02/2016  1.8
07/03/2016  1.7
07/04/2016  1.6
07/05/2016  1.6
07/06/2016  1.6
07/07/2016  1.7
07/08/2016  1.6
07/09/2016  1.5
07/10/2016  1.5
07/11/2016  1.4
07/12/2016  1.4
07/13/2016  1.4
07/14/2016  1.4
07/15/2016  1.4
07/16/2016  1.3
07/17/2016  1.3
07/18/2016  1.3
07/19/2016  1.3
07/20/2016  1.3
07/21/2016  1.2
07/22/2016  1.2
07/23/2016  1.2
07/24/2016  1.2
07/25/2016  1.2
07/26/2016  0
07/27/2016  0
07/28/2016  1.2
07/29/2016  1.1
07/30/2016  1
07/31/2016  1
08/01/2016  1
08/02/2016  1.1
08/03/2016  1.9
08/04/2016  2.1
08/05/2016  1.6
08/06/2016  1.3
08/07/2016  1.2
08/08/2016  1.4
08/09/2016  1.4
08/10/2016  1.2
08/11/2016  1.2
08/12/2016  1.1
08/13/2016  1.1
08/14/2016  1.1
08/15/2016  1.1
08/16/2016  1
08/17/2016  15.9
08/18/2016  11.4
08/19/2016  7.4
08/20/2016  6
08/21/2016  5.3
08/22/2016  7.8
08/23/2016  10.3
08/24/2016  5.9
08/25/2016  3.5
08/26/2016  2.1
08/27/2016  1.7
08/28/2016  1
08/29/2016  0.7
08/30/2016  9.2
08/31/2016  9.2
09/01/2016  5.5
09/02/2016  3.5
09/03/2016  2.1
09/04/2016  1.3
09/05/2016  0.8
09/06/2016  0.5
09/07/2016  0.6
09/08/2016  0.7
09/09/2016  0.6
09/10/2016  0.6
09/11/2016  0.6
09/12/2016  0.6
09/13/2016  0.8
09/14/2016  0.7
09/15/2016  0.6
09/16/2016  0.6
09/17/2016  0.6
09/18/2016  0.8
09/19/2016  1
09/20/2016  1.1
09/21/2016  1.1
```

I would like to :
First, find the local minimum within nonoverlapping 5-day windows for the entire time series.
Second, extract series of minima and find the turning points which are at least 1.11 times smaller than their neighboring minima.
Third, once, the turning points are found, I would like to reconstruct the data by linear interpolation between the points.

Does anyone have an idea or an example of code?

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at options like `pandas` or `numpy`?

Comment: This is fairly straightforward and there are many ways to do this, depending on how DIY you want to be. What have you tried? How did it fall short?