# Finding rate of change across date range using local maxima and local minima

Tags: r, pandas, numpy, spreadsheet, rate

My question is somewhat [like this unanswered one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/57059797).

Background: I have a CSV file of battery percentage information. It is thousands of rows long. The basic format is as follows:

```
datetime,battery_percentage
2022-01-08 16:24:58.459,84
2022-01-08 18:45:33.322,76
2022-01-08 20:41:51.111,68
2022-01-08 21:56:43.232,63
2022-01-09 00:15:08.888,49
2022-01-09 01:18:31.488,41
2022-01-09 02:42:14.234,27
2022-01-09 08:07:16.123,12
2022-01-09 16:46:06.069,87
2022-01-09 17:04:16.285,100
2022-01-09 18:30:03.423,100
2022-01-09 23:51:39.321,97
2022-01-10 02:33:32.690,89
2022-01-10 04:06:01.999,72
2022-01-10 08:15:27.897,61
2022-01-10 16:35:09.270,52
2022-01-10 17:09:33.420,27
2022-01-10 21:00:41.420,9
2022-01-10 23:24:55.122,98
2022-01-11 00:17:35.186,100
2022-01-11 11:43:16.965,92
2022-01-11 12:11:27.351,87
2022-01-11 15:49:44.161,55
2022-01-11 21:04:43.689,42
2022-01-11 22:07:13.345,38
```

I would like to find *some* way to calculate the local maxima and local minima around inflection points—i.e. if the number hits a high point (circled in green below) and starts to decrease, that would mean the battery is discharging; if the number hits a low point (circled in red below) and starts to increase, that would mean the battery is charging.

The ultimate goal here would be to see whenever the battery hits a maximum (green), we then look to the next minimum (red) to calculate the rate of discharge. I have yet to find a reliable way to do this in Google Sheets or Tableau. I am not opposed to using numpy or pandas, I just don't have much experience in them.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1aKa.png]

Comment: Did you mean to tag `r`? or are you looking for a possible solution in `r` as well? I didn't want to remove it, if so.

Comment: I'm pretty much just looking to learn a way of approaching this topic in a repeatable manner besides doing derivatives on paper or eyeballing rate of change from a chart, so I figured `r` folks might be worth bringing into the game.

Comment: Here is a recent bountied post in `r` that talks about picking out peaks that might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70582716/picking-out-peaks-that-fit-a-pattern

Answer (score 0):

One way using `scipy.signal.find_peaks`. Since it cannot detect a maxima at the either end of an array, use `numpy.pad` as well:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = df["battery_percentage"]

maxima, _ = find_peaks(np.pad(s, 1))
maxima -= 1 # This is to revert the changed indices from padding above
```

Since `find_peaks` can only detect local maxima, we reverse original array, shift it up by global maximum, then pad:

```
minima, _ = find_peaks(np.pad(-s + s.max(), 1))
minima -= 1
```

Visualize result using `matplotlib`:

```
s.plot(figsize=(20, 10))
plt.scatter(maxima, s[maxima], s=1000, facecolors='none', edgecolors='g')
plt.scatter(minima, s[minima], s=1000, facecolors='none', edgecolors='r')
```

Plot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take derivatives. See example below.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1],
                       [2],
                       [3],
                       [4],
                       [3.5],
                       [2.5],
                       [1.5],
                       [2],
                       [2.4],
                       [3.5]], columns=['data'])
```

[image]

Taking derivatives:

```py
df['increasing'] = df.data.diff()
df['decreasing'] = df.data.diff(-1)
df['local_max'] = ((df.increasing>0) & (df.decreasing>0))
df['local_min'] = ((df.increasing<0) & (df.decreasing<0))
```

Result

```py
    data increasing decreasing  local_max   local_min
0   1.0   NaN           -1.0    False   False
1   2.0   1.0           -1.0    False   False
2   3.0   1.0           -1.0    False   False
3   4.0   1.0           0.5     True    False
4   3.5   -0.5          1.0     False   False
5   2.5   -1.0          1.0     False   False
6   1.5   -1.0          -0.5    False   True
7   2.0   0.5           -0.4    False   False
8   2.4   0.4           -1.1    False   False
9   3.5   1.1           NaN     False   False
```